# react - TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
class Login extends Component {

    render() {
        const username = "me@domain.com  ";
        console.log(username)
        const password = this.refs.password;
        const creds = {
            username: username.value.trim(),
            password: password.value.trim()
        };
        const errorMessage  = this.props;

        return ( ... ) } }
```

console shows "me@domain.com" yet it's erroring on `username: username.value.trim()`

```
  11 | console.log(username)
  12 | const password = this.refs.password;
  13 | const creds = {
> 14 |     username: username.value.trim(),
  15 |     password: password.value.trim()
  16 | };
  17 | const errorMessage  = this.props;
```

Comment: remove `value`, use `username.trim()`

Comment: well not sure how a string has a value.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`username` is not an `object` but a string string and hence you would write

```
const username = "me@domain.com  ";
const creds = {
        username: username.trim(),
        password: password.trim()
    };
```

Also you shouldn't use `string refs` as they are deprecated.

Comment: how do I set a string as an object?

Comment: @whoisearth `const username = "me@domain.com  ";` defines username as  a string and since you use username.value, you indicate that username is an object with one of the key as value

Answer (score 5):

```
username.value.trim()
```

`username` itself a String, you need not to get value out of it. Just trim.

```
const creds = {
        username: username.trim(),
        password: password.value.trim()
    };
```

Comment: nope, not for password, because op is using string refs, so to get the value he needs to use `this.refs.password.value`, btw congo for 100k (very close) :)

Comment: @MayankShukla Ahh yes. how did I miss. Editing. Thankyou :)